# datetime comparison in ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two DateTime objects:

`time1 = '2016-04-05T15:30:00';` 
`time2 = '2016-04-05T14:48:41.7609724Z';`

In my HTML, I have:

`<div ng-if="time1 > time2">result</div>`. This works well.

Now I want to know if time1 minus 30 minutes still > time2. So I did:

`<div ng-if="time1 - 30*60*1000 > time2">result</div>` This doesn't work.

It's like I can only compare the datetime object directly using `>` or `<`, but I can't do math on it using `-` or `+`. To verify:

`<div>{{time1 > time2}}</div>` shows `True`.

`<div>{{time1 < time2}}</div>` shows `False`.

`<div>{{time1 - time2}}</div>` shows `NaN`. I expect this to be a number of the result in milliseconds.

**QUESTION**: How to do math on the DateTime with `ng-if`, **e.g.** adding minutes on one DateTime, then compare these two DateTime.

**NOTES**: Some may say it's because my `time1` and `time2` have different format. I've verified this is not the issue. Same issue happens when I change `time2` to same format as `time1`.

Comment: You may want to use a function for that, because dates don't implicitely convert to miliseconds when hit with a unary converter

Comment: The weird thing is it works on this website: http://plnkr.co/edit/fNB11U6KmFszdV3lMAPJ?p=preview

Comment: I'd suggest using  `moment`: `moment(time1).isAfter(time2)`. You can also subtract/add minutes to whichever date you see fit, before the `isAfter/isBefore` check is run. See the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Is there a proper way to do this inside `ng-if`?

Comment: @YabinSong I suggest converting both to `Date` objects in the controller (Using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)) - This is something to do on the controler side.

Comment: These appear to be strings, not Date objects so they are being compared as strings (which "works" for the OP format). Also, *time1* appears to be local and *time2* is UTC, so the difference between the two is dependent on the host system time zone setting.

Comment: @RobG I think you're right.. these are strings already...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a filter, then you can use standard angular paradigms. Using my example your markup will look like the following:

```
{{date1 | myFilter: date2: '-'}}
```

And the filter will look something like:

```
.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(date1, date2, operation) {
    switch(operation) {
      case '===':
        return date1.toString() === date2.toString();
        break;
      case '-':
        return (date1 - date2).toString();
        break
    }
  }
})
```

here is a plunker demonstrating the concept:

https://plnkr.co/edit/gqQ0OsdR6cN7u4VM5AvP?p=preview

Comment: I wanna check if time1 - 30minutes > time2. Is it doable?

Comment: The overall concept is to use a filter for this. You can put whatever logic you want to calculate the output of the filter.

Comment: This also compares strings, not objects. If *date1* and *date2* really are Date objects, then `date2 - date1` will return a number that is the difference in milliseconds between the two.

Comment: I think this is too much for a single comparison in my case.. especially it won't be reuse anywhere else in my project. I'll just do it at server side. It's much more clear and easy. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a controller method for the comparison of the dates.

With the Date object you can do basic math (subtraction and adding) and afterward you can get the time in millisconds with `getTime()` from date object.
Then you'll only have to do some scaling to minutes (*1000 *60) and you can compare the minutes.

With a `$watchGroup` (angular >=1.3) you can watch every variable that's relevant for an update of you time delta. You could also use `ng-change` on every input field but watch is easier to write.

Something like in the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jycoj65q/) should work.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.date1 = new Date();
  vm.diff = 35;
  vm.date2 = new Date(vm.date1);
  vm.date2.setMinutes(vm.date1.getMinutes() + vm.diff);

  vm.date = {
    deltaMinutes: vm.diff,
    deltaBool: Date((vm.date2 - vm.date1))
  };

  vm.updateDate = function(date) {
    //console.log('changed', date);
    var deltaDate = new Date((vm.date2 - vm.date1));
    vm.date.deltaMinutes = (deltaDate.getTime() / 1000 / 60);
    vm.date.deltaBool = vm.date.deltaMinutes >= vm.diff;
    //console.log(vm.diff);
  };

  vm.open1 = function() {

    vm.popup1.opened = true;
    console.log('clicked open', vm.popup1);
  };

  vm.open2 = function() {
    vm.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.$watchGroup(['mainCtrl.date1', 'mainCtrl.date2', 'mainCtrl.diff'], vm.updateDate);

  //$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  //$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  //vm.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  vm.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };
  vm.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
  time difference in minutes:
  <input ng-model="mainCtrl.diff"/>
  <br/>date1:
  <p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mainCtrl.date1" is-open="mainCtrl.popup1.opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" uib-datepicker-popup alt-input-formats="mainCtrl.altInputFormats"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mainCtrl.open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
  </p>
  <uib-timepicker ng-model="mainCtrl.date1" ng-change="mainCtrl.changed(mainCtrl.date1)" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>

  date2:
  <p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup class="form-control" ng-model="mainCtrl.date2"  is-open="mainCtrl.popup2.opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="mainCtrl.altInputFormats" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mainCtrl.open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
  </p>
  <uib-timepicker ng-model="mainCtrl.date2" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
  <br/>time difference in minutes = {{mainCtrl.date.deltaMinutes}}
  <div ng-if="mainCtrl.date.deltaBool" class="alert alert-success">
    date1 is at least {{mainCtrl.diff}} Minutes before date2
  </div>
</div>
```